# How to properly use time.time()

Tags: python

I am trying to time a running function. But I need to know how many hours/minutes/seconds does it takes. I am using time.time(), but I don't understand the output. How can I convert this output in terms of how many hours/minutes/seconds does a function took? Or, if there is another proper library?

```
import time
starttime = time.time()
x=0
for i in range(100000):
    x+=i
endtime = time.time()
print('Job took: ', endtime-starttime)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)?

Comment: The time() function returns the number of seconds passed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00

Comment: See [the docs for `time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html#time.time). It returns the number of _seconds_ passed since the beginning of the UNIX epoch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using `time.perf_counter` instead of `time.time`, and using `timedelta` to format the units:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import time
>>> starttime = time.perf_counter()
>>> x=0
>>> for i in range(100000):
...     x+=i
...
>>> duration = timedelta(seconds=time.perf_counter()-starttime)
>>> print('Job took: ', duration)
Job took:  0:00:00.015017
```

The benefit of using `perf_counter` is that it won't be impacted by weird things like the timezone or system clock changing while you're measuring, and its resolution is guaranteed to be as high as possible (which may be important if you're timing very quick events).

In either case, the return value is measured in seconds, but you need to know what function it came from in order to know what the float value corresponds to.  `timedelta` is a nicer way to represent a duration than a pure float IMO because it includes the units.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works exactly like I want.

Answer (score 1):

`time.time()`:

> The time() function returns the number of seconds passed since epoch.
>
> For Unix system, January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 at UTC is epoch (the point
>   where time begins).
>
> ```
> import time
> seconds = time.time()
> print("Seconds since epoch =", seconds)
> ```

This might not be what you want

Answer (score 0):

`time.time()` gives the seconds when you started a process. Therefore `endtime-starttime` gives you the amount of seconds between the beginning and the end of the loop.
A preferable way to stop time in python is to use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
import datetime
starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
x=0
for i in range(100000):
    x+=i
endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = endtime - starttime
print('Job took: ', diff.days, diff.seconds, diff.microseconds)
```